# jQuery submit()-event to override form action

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, jquery

I have a form, and I have some jquery code to override the submit process. But it's not working and there are no errors. I have simplified the sample code, hope I made no typos.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code? It doesn't come to the point where I get the alert(). The click() event works fine.

I tried setting an id to the form. still nothing.

Using jquery-1.4.2.min.js

```
  <form name="checkout_shipping" action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <div class="contentText">
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0); document.checkout_shipping.submit();">
          <td width="75%" style="padding-left: 15px;">Flat price</td>
          <td>$8.00</td>
          <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="flat_flat" onclick="this.form.submit();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1); document.checkout_shipping.submit();">
          <td>Pick-up</td>
          <td>$0.00</td>
          <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="pickup_pickup" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.submit();" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    $('form[name=checkout_shipping]').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Houston we have contact!');
      $.ajax({
        url: '/includes/checkout/payment.php',
        data: false, // false for testing
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // ...
        },
        success: function(data) {
          // ...
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're submitting the form bypasses the event handelers.

Instead of:

```
 document.checkout_shipping.submit();
```

Use

```
 $(this).closest('form').submit();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/6uZuS/

Full code:

```
<form name="checkout_shipping" action="checkout.php" method="post"> 
    <div class="contentText"> 
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"> 
            <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0); $(this).closest('form').submit();"> 
                    <td width="75%" style="padding-left: 15px;">Flat price</td> 
                    <td>$8.00</td> 
                    <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="flat_flat" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();" /></td> 
                </tr> 
                <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1); $(this).closest('form').submit();"> 
                    <td>Pick-up</td> 
                    <td>$0.00</td> 
                    <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="pickup_pickup" checked="checked" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();" /></td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 
        </div> 
</form> 


 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('form[name=checkout_shipping]').submit(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Got you!');
           });
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: No erros, didn't work. Just submits the form and reloads the page. Even though your example did the trick in the link.

Comment: I'ved copied the HTML/script from JS Fiddle that works for me. Did you test the code on JSFiddle?

Comment: I was mistaken, I had a typo when I copied your code and named an id. It does work. Thank you sooo much! Weee. I would never have guessed it was just an event bypass issue.

Comment: Not a problem. I was in your shoes not too long ago with the jQuery Validate plugin, calling .submit bypasses the hooks it uses for client validation. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y6z3j/1/) **or**

```
<form name="checkout_shipping" id="checkout_shipping" action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <div class="contentText">
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
        <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0);">
          <td width="75%" style="padding-left: 15px;">Flat price</td>
          <td>$8.00</td>
          <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="flat_flat" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1);">
          <td>Pick-up</td>
          <td>$0.00</td>
          <td align="right"><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="pickup_pickup" checked="checked" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkout_shipping').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Houston we have contact!');
});
})
</script>
```

Comment: No errors but didn't work. A regular form action is what I get. No alert, no ajax.

Comment: You must change your onclick event to : `$(this).parents('form').submit();` or to `$(this).closest('form').submit();`

Comment: Tried Splash-X solution. It does not work in my environment though. Like always no firebug errors.

Comment: @tim The question is did you try either of our solutions on JSFiddle? They both work in IE9 and FF 8 for me (mine and Fedya's)

Comment: Guys your solutions did work after all. See other post. Thank you.